# Base64 Encoded String as TypeScript Template Literal Type

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

As the title suggests, I'm trying to define a return type of a JsonWebToken string, and my best attempt looks like the following:

```js
interface EncodedString<T extends string> extends String {
  [index: number]: T;
}

// /[A–Z0–9+/]/i
type Base64UrlCharacter =
  'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'G' | 'H' | 'I' | 'J' | 'K' | 'L' | 'M' | 'N' | 'O' | 'P' | 'Q' | 'R' | 'S' | 'T' | 'U' | 'V' | 'W' | 'X' | 'Y' | 'Z' |
  'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm' | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z' |
  '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '+' | '/';
// /[A–Z0–9+/=]/i
type Base64Character = Base64UrlCharacter | '=';
type Base64UrlString = EncodedString<Base64UrlCharacter>;
type Base64String = EncodedString<Base64Character>
type JsonWebTokenMessage = `${Base64UrlString}.${Base64UrlString}`;
type JsonWebTokenString = `${JsonWebTokenMessage}.${Base64UrlString}`;
```

However, when I do this, I'm getting the following error: `TS2322: Type 'Base64UrlString' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.` I don't understand what's happening here, and I was hoping the community at large might be able to help me.

Comment: I don't see the point in making a type for this... Where would you even use this? It would also be extremely frustrating to work with - just think of slicing the string or trying to append a plain `string` to it - you'll probably get errors when trying to use the results.

Comment: @jcalz yes, the question was meant to be "How do I define a type that reflects the structure of a JsonWebToken string?" I've seen some inventive solutions for defining types, like defining a decorator that will enforce a class implements a static interface (such as `String` implementing `StringConstructor`). I wasn't sure if there was some magic to be leveraged, since `string` means any length, any format, any characters.

Comment: caTS brings up a very good point: how do you plan to use such a type?  There’s no point in trying to teach the compiler how to recognize valid/invalid jsonwebtoken strings unless these strings are going to be present as hard coded string literals in your typescript programs.  If you only deal with the actual strings at runtime, then this is probably an xy problem and you could use a nominal-ish type instead.  Could you [edit] the question to clarify the use case?

Comment: @jcalz I don't really have a specific use case in mind, more that I was trying to be as descriptive as possible in the interface. An analogy to the argument I'm making is that `Buffer` is basically `Uint8Array` which could also potentially be expressed as `number[]`, however there are more specific types because they represent specific things/behavior. Similarly, a JWT isn't *just* a `string` and is actually structured as a 2-3 length sequence of string delimited by periods encoded in base64. The first two segments are encoded data, and the third is an optional hash.

Comment: If you don't have a use case then it's hard to know how to advise here. Imagine I asked you to train a dog to only eat *organic* dog treats. Would you immediately set to work on teaching such a concept to the dog, or would you want to know *why*? Even if organic food is important, it doesn't mean the dog could or should be the one thinking about that. Right now you are asking how to express the structure of a JWT *to the TypeScript compiler*, but I don't know *why*. Certainly the structure is important, but that doesn't mean the compiler needs to understand it.

Comment: Let me clarify my earlier suggestion about using a nominal-ish type.  You could use a [branded primitive](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) to define `JsonWebTokenString` as a subtype of `string`, like [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrXRVW).  The compiler has no idea what really makes a string a `JsonWebTokenString` and in fact we are lying to it (this is like training a dog to only accept a treat from a particular box which we've labeled "organic") but this is far simpler than anything involving template literal types.

Comment: Does that meet your needs? If so I'd be happy to write up an answer; if not, what, specifically, is lacking?  (Pls ping me via @jcalz, thx)

Comment: @jcalz I think you've highlighted a misunderstanding on my part about defining types. I was hoping to provide a more descriptive type than just `string`, but there's nothing directly enforceable about saying the string is a JWT. I also just realized there's a full library for Node.js to perform JWT operations (`jose`), so I'm thinking I might re-evaluate my approach to the entire project. There are some design decisions in `jose` I'm not fond of, but I might be able to wrap it for my uses or leverage the work there rather than re-inventing it myself.

Comment: Thank you for entertaining the musings of an overzealous developer, but I'll probably proceed under the assumption that my original idea was a lost cause.